# Update all rows on table based on value from other table that gets multiple values from third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

so I have three tables in a database on a Microsoft SQL Server.

The system is an example one for learning, and it contains table A, which is schools that have an id and a total amount of money spent on buying stuff.

Table B contains the stuff you can buy with an id and price

Table C contains all orders, and order_id, school_id, stuff_id, and amount of stuff

My problem is this, I have to create a trigger that when a value is inserted in table C updates all schools total amount of money spent. And I can't figure out how to do that. Especially since i have to count the amount of things bought aswell.

If you want to see the sql as I do you can do it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/265f0

Comment: Create a view that calculates the totals instead having them in the table ,for real time values. You can then update the totals in the table every night in a scheduled job if you want it for reporting purposes.

Comment: Don't you want triggers to handle `INSERT` (new order), `UPDATE` (changed order) and `DELETE` (deleted order)? Have you thought through how you'll handle price changes, e.g. a school places an order, the price changes, then the school changes the quantity ordered? Or would you rather prevent direct changes to the tables and force users to go through stored procedures that also implement sanity checks, e.g. quantity ordered is greater than zero? If you go with trigger(s), keep in mind that they fire once per statement, but a statement may affect multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a query that is like this:

```
select c.school_id, sum(b.price)
from b join
     c
     on b.stuff_id = b.stuff_id
group by c.school_id;
```

You *can* use triggers.  But this gets much more complicated, because you have to handle deleted and updating records, as well as inserting them.